# I want to pick the words from a list of words, when there is a no vowel till the given number of char

Tags: java, string

```
class Test{   
    public static void main(String[] args) {     
        String line = "ALONE AMEND DATES DAWNS DEALS LEMON LENDS";
        int maxVowelAtChar = 4;     

        // need the help for this function.  
        String pure = myFunc(line, maxVowelChar);  
        System.out.println(pure);   
    }
}
```

Now it should print :

> DAWNS LENDS

After `maxVowelAtChar` there should not be any vowel. the count start from last character of word. "ALONE" does not qualify since it has vowel at char 1 & 3, similarly "LEMON" has vowel at char 2. "DAWNS" qualifies since it has no vowels upto 3rd characters(4th one is A). Help me please.

Comment: @TestUser, I'm still lost, why does `DAWN` qualify?

Comment: @ Keoki Zee: it not the homework.

Comment: @ Elite Gentleman: "DAWNS" qaulifies, since the vowel is placed at 4th character, counting from the last. And maxVowelAtChar has value of 4. The function should only remove the words from the list, which has vowel placed at postion 1,2 or 3 (i.e. less than 4)

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what is the purpose of this program?

Comment: -1 ALONE would not qualify because of 'A' (5th character counting from last). This is very confusing -- please clarify.

Comment: @TestUser, can you clarify why LEMON doesn't qualify but LENDS does?

Comment: @vineet, because the vowel in LEMON is @postion 2(and 4), counting reversibly which is less than 4(value of maxVowelAtChar) so it does not. While LENDS qualifies since the vowel is postioned at 4 th char which is not less than 4.

Comment: @ JesperE: i am using this program in order to build word puzzle solver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED: This code passes the clarified requirements. Changed to count from end backwards.**

Before you criticise, see notes below.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String line = "ALONE AMEND DATES DAWNS DEALS LEMON LENDS";
    for (int maxVowelAtChar = 1; maxVowelAtChar < 6; maxVowelAtChar++)
    {
        String pure = myFunc(line, maxVowelAtChar);
        System.out.println(maxVowelAtChar + ": " + pure);
    }
}

private static String myFunc(String line, int maxVowelAtChar)
{
    String pure = "";

    for (String word : line.split("\\s"))
    {
        // This regex is also sensitive to word length ie not being 5 like all test data
        if (word.matches("^.{" + (word.length() - maxVowelAtChar + 1) + "}[^aeiouAEIOU]*$"))
            pure += word + " ";
    }

    return pure.trim();
}

Output:
1: ALONE AMEND DATES DAWNS DEALS LEMON LENDS
2: AMEND DATES DAWNS DEALS LEMON LENDS
3: AMEND DAWNS DEALS LENDS  
4: DAWNS LENDS
5:
```

This code has been simplified to illustrate the core of the solution. "Real" code would use a StringBuffer instead of `String += String`.

What makes this work is the dynamic regex passed to `matches` that means "must end with n non-vowels"

Comment: Please enote the OP talks about counting from the last -- although I re-read the question and some of the examples themselves do not make sense.

Comment: Thank you bro!! In this case it really print the output, but when i change the parameter for maxVowelAtChar to 3, it does not print the required output. for maxVowelAtChar=5; output: -blank- for maxVowelAtChar=4; output: DAWNS LENDS; for maxVowelAtChar=3; output: AMEND DAWNS DEALS LENDS;(since after 3 char none has vowel, but ALONE & LEMON has vowel in 1st, 2nd char resp. so not in the list)

Comment: similarly if maxVowelAtChar=2 then only ALONE will be removed and for value 1 there wont be any word removal